# Google Analytics integration in iOS SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

It's my first time integrating google analytics in my app.I'm just following this official document [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift)

I already have a tracker ID. I don't want to create configuration file. 
How can I use that tracker ID and how can I integrate Google analytics?

Comment: create a configuration file and replace your tracker id with new tracker id.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create extension of UIView Conroller.

extension UIViewController {
    func setScreeName(name: String) {
        self.title = name
        self.sendScreenView()
    }

    func sendScreenView() {
        let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: self.title)
        let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
        tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }

    func trackEvent(category: String, action: String, label: String, value: NSNumber?) {
        let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
        let trackDictionary = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory(category, action: action, label: label, value: value)
        tracker.send(trackDictionary.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }
}

For Each view Controller viewdidload() you add following code
self.title = self.navigationItem.title!
    self.sendScreenView()
```